# Is there any tool to trace dependency of Excel cells and VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, dependencies

Excel has a functionality to trace the `precedents` and `dependents` of a cell (via menu `Tools > Auditing`). For instance, if we have `= C3 + 1` in `C4`, then Excel can trace that `C4` is a dependent of `C3` (`C3`is a precedent of `C4`).

As VBA code also has impact to Excel cells, I would like to know if there is any tool to trace  the dependency between VBA code and Excel cells.

For example, if there is a line of VBA code `Range("C4").Value = Range("C3").Value + 1`, is there a tool to trace that `C4` might be a dependent of `C3`?

Also, if there is a line of VBA code `Range("C4").Value = 5`, is there a tool to trace that `C4` might be modified by this piece of code?

Comment: There was a long discussion about this recently at the [EUSPRIG Yahoo Group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/eusprig/message/2392). I think the most helpful solution - but not exactly what you want - was the software package "ACBA Tools.xla" available free [from here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ACBA_Functions/files/)

Answer (score 2):

Changes made by VBA cannot be tracked easily (because cells may be modified in arbitrary way by a function or passed to a function as string).

There is something you can do but it's a little bit tricky and I guess it won't really satisfy you: you can detect if a cell has any dependency.

How it works? Write a macro like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
End Sub
```

You may log to the immediate window the changed cells. Now change a cell value, in the immediate window you'll see all cells that depend on the cell you changed. Disadvantages?

- Unfortunately the inverse process is not possible: you can't select a cell and see all its dependencies.
- The process cannot be (really) automated because from code usually you don't know valid values for cells (you may guess by cell type but you can't be sure because of rules, "0" may be a valid value and "1" no, for example).
- It can't really detect every dependency (if two given values won't produce a change in a cell then you won't see that dependency).
- For large worksheets it can be pretty tedious so it's indicated only if applied to a small set of cells (what if I change/move this cell? Will it affect anything?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the following answers your question - but I thought it was helpful.

The `Range` object has a `Precedents` and `Dependents` property. This allows you, from within VBA, to do what the menu `Tools->auditing` does in the UI. (I have to acknowledge @Bathsheba's answer to this recent question https://stackoverflow.com/a/20635795/1967396 for teaching me this…).

```
Dim prec, p
Set prec = [C4].Precedents  ' [C4] is shorthand for Range("C4")
For Each p in prec
  Debug.Print "Precedent found: " & p.Address
next p
```

Note - you do need the `Set` ; otherwise you end up with the **values** of the precedents, rather than references to the **objects** (in which case you could not see the address…)

You can do the same thing with `.Dependents`, obviously:

This does not answer the "if there is a line of VBA code that creates a relationship" question… which is especially tricky since you can have cells modified by variable and unpredictable offsets, e.g.

```
For j = 1 To n
  [B5].Offset(j+3, 2+k) = [A2].Offset(Int(DateValue(Now)) Mod 3, 1)
Next j
```

Which cell depends on what will depend on the date you run this script…

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will be of use to you. I wrote a macro so that you may select a range and either show the precedence or dependence for each cell in the range.

```
Sub tracerange()

On Error Resume Next

    Dim R As Range
    Dim DorP As Variant
    R = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    DorP = LCase(Application.InputBox("Please input Precedents or Dependece (P or D):", , , , , , , Type:=2))
        For Each R In Selection
            If DorP = "p" Then
                R.ShowPrecedents
            Else
                R.ShowDependents
            End If
            DoEvents
        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.