# VBA check line in regexpr

Tags: excel, vba

I try to check consistanty of formulas for a given line in VBA.

Concretely : all line's reference in a formula must be this of the current line.

Ex of cell's concatanation : a2&" "&b2 ==> I want avoid (check) something like : a2&" "&b3

I use for this rexexpr but I can't find right syntax.

My code :

```
Dim RegExpr As Object
Dim ChkSheet As Worksheet
Dim i as Long
Dim Count as Long

Set ChkSheet = ActiveSheet

for i = 2 to 15

Set RegExpr = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

'-------- PARAM REGEXPR --------'
Ic = False
Fi = ChkSheet.Cells(i, 3).Formula
Fw = "[A-Z]+[^" & i & "]"
'-------------------------------'

RegExpr.Pattern = Fw
RegExpr.IgnoreCase = Ic
RegExpr.Global = True

If RegExpr.Test(Fi) = True Then
        MsgBox "Problem found, line : " & i & ", formula : " & Fi
        Count = Count + 1
End If

Next i

MsgBox "Errors : " & Count
```

this : "[A-Z]+[^" & i & "]" doesn't work anymore from 10th line

Thanks for help

Comment: I disagree with the person who thinks this question should be closed. How to write the correct regex to make this program run correctly is very much about programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks the community to provide code instead of asking an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

Solving this using regular expressions would be difficult. Complexities include `$`, formulae with fully qualified ranges (e.g. `Worksheet!A1`), named ranges and allowing for `R1C1` notation. Supporting named ranges probably makes solving the problem impossible with regular expressions.

However, there is a VBA solution. Suppose the cell containing the formula is `$A$1`. You can use the `.Precedents` property on a `Range` to examine all the cells on which `$A$1` depends. Then compare the rows of those cells:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = Range("$A$1")
    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    For Each cell In rng.Precedents
        'Am I in the same row? Stop if not.
        If rng.Row <> cell.Row Then Stop
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I googled for this solution (it was the first one that came to mind) but my search led me to an answer "it cannot be done". I should know better than believe everything I read on the internet… or learn to read the question better (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297150/is-there-any-tool-to-trace-dependency-of-excel-cells-and-vba-code/20637502#20637502 )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your regular expression (you probably figured that our by yourself).

Let's look at line 11, where you test for:

```
[A-Z]+[^11]
```

In regex that means "zero or one of characters A-Z, followed not by one of the characters `1, 1`.  So you are not testing for "not `11`", you are testing for "next character not 1"

I will give some thought as to the correct solution… but for now, this is the reason your expression fails when you hit the double digits.